# Alterar informações com JS-JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

Estou tentando alterar um determinado valor dentro do meu código html, através do JS-JEQUERY, mas não esta alteando, minha logica esta errada ?

Segue o código:

```js
var valor = "texto";
$('.botao botao-comprar principal grande desativo with-popover').on('click', function () {
   
   $(this).data('data-content', valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" class="botao botao-comprar principal grande desativo with-popover" rel="popover" data-placement="left" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Selecione uma opção de atributo disponível." data-original-title="IMPORTANTE">
  <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Comprar
</a>
```

Comment: Cara, qual o valor da sua variável `texto` (`var valor = texto;`)? Porque se for um texto mesmo, como o nome sugere, não faz sentido você utilizar incremento `valor++;`

Comment: corrigindo, estava fazendo uns testes

Comment: Faltou adicionar os pontos nas classes, vc só colocou na primeira: `$('.botao .botao-comprar .principal .grande .desativo .with-popover')`

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem, você está querendo manipular o atributo **data** do botão. Aí no caso como você já utilizou o método `data` não precisa escrever dentro dele **data-content**, mas sim apenas **content**, tbm para manipular um elemento Html não precisa colocar todas as classes existentes nele, apenas a primeira já basta, se a classe for única, senão coloque uma específica tipo **$('.botao-comprar')** ou use um `id` **$(#botão)**:

```js
var valor = "texto";
$('.botao').on('click', function () {
   
   $(this).data('content', valor);

   console.log('O data-content agora é: ' + $('a').data('content'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" class="botao botao-comprar principal grande desativo with-popover" rel="popover" data-placement="left" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Selecione uma opção de atributo disponível." data-original-title="IMPORTANTE">
  <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Comprar
</a>
```

Comment: Só uma correção broder: não é bom colocar apenas a classe `.botao` no seletor, porque pode ter outros na página. É bom o seletor ser mais específico, tipo `$(".botao-comprar")`. Essa classe me parece ser mais específica.

Comment: @Sam sim, concerteza. Desatenção mesmo! Obrigado man.